# response is empty when trying send a request GET with vanilla JS to express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I want to create a request GET that returns a `json` data type with `ajax`

The route is so simply like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ answer: 42})
});
```

When I open `/` in the browser it render this:

[image]
[image]

All ok, **but** I trying to get answer json with XMLHttpRequest vanilla JS (no jquery):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.responseType = 'json'
xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert(this.response) // response is 'null'
})
xhr.send();
```

the `response` property is `null` and thw browser look like this:
[image]
[image]
I get nothing back. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the code It must be a cross domain issue. The reason it works from postman is it handle the preflight automatically. You need to enable cors in your express server like this.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ answer: 42})
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening");
});
```

Hope it helps.